# EF Core: PrincipalKey without UniqueConstraint?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I've been messing around with EF Core 3.1 trying to setup a relationship between two classes. The trick is the composite key on the one class which the other one is only related to through one part.

Consider the following:

```cs
public class A
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<B> B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

...
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<A>(b =>
    {
        b.HasKey(x => new {x.Id, x.Foo});

        b.HasMany(x => x.B)
            .WithOne()
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id);
    });
}
```

Which creates the following migration:

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "A",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Foo = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_A", x => new { x.Id, x.Foo });
        table.UniqueConstraint("AK_A_Id", x => x.Id);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "B",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
        Bar = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        AId = table.Column<long>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_B", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_B_A_AId",
            column: x => x.AId,
            principalTable: "A",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_B_AId",
    table: "B",
    column: "AId");
```

Which is almost what I want, except for the UniqueConstraint on table A! Is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you tried simply deleting the unique constraint from the migration and running a few example queries with example data afterwards? Not that I would find this _relations_ to be correct (because at least the `WithOne()` part of the `HasMany(x => x.B)` is wrong). But why not just try it out.

Comment: So, you have two As, with key `"abc",1` and `"def",1`. And now you have a `B` with an `AId` of `1`. To which of the two As does it belong?

Comment: The phrase `PrincipalKey without UniqueConstraint` is self-contradicting. By definition, a primary key is unique. Otherwise it couldn't even be a key, much less a primary key. A primary key is the one out of the many candidate keys that was chosen to *uniquely* identify a record. All candidate keys are unique, but the PK is the one chosen for use

Comment: @Namoshek Honestly I didn't try because I don't really want to manually edit the migrations files and thought to look for a proper solution :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I get your point but what if we are talking about an aggregation relationship rather than a composition. Isn't this supported?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yea I get the phrase is contradicting but I thought to use it to explain what I would achieve. I get that the model definition isn't the right way to define what I wanted to achieve but it was the closest I could get.

Comment: @MattImmer You are actually supposed to **verify** and **correct** migration files as required. These files are not supposed to be used in their auto-generated form only. Especially when making schema changes which require data to be moved between tables, there is no other way of doing it than writing a manual migration script. So, just go ahead and try it. ;)

Comment: @Namoshek Oh yea for sure! I've seen it do some weird stuff so I always verify :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. And not because of EF Core, but the definition of the relationship multiplicity (cardinality).

The direct FK relationship from dependent to principal is to (has multiplicity) **one** (1) (or zero-or-one 0..1 in case of optional relationship), i.e. the FK must identify exactly one principal record. That's why the referenced principal key must be unique, which is satisfied by primary or unique key constraint.

What you are asking allows dependent record referencing more than one (i.e. many) matching principal records. In other words, to *many* cardinality. Which cannot be achieved with FK in the dependent table, but would require the typical for [many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) relationship intermediate link (join) entity/table.

Comment: What is we ignore my attempt to define it? Is there a way to do it without the MTM table? I guess it is a sort of aggregation relationship and I thought the relation would be achievable without the need for an extra table.

Comment: @MattImmer It's either OTM with FK at dependent, or MTM with extra table. There is no other option in relational database.

Comment: Alright that's also how I was taught databases work :) I was just thinking if EF Core provided any means of doing this relationship. It is a pretty straightforward relationship to handle using joins and maybe EF Core could handle that abstraction.